# Help template framework for a java web application?

Tags: documentation-viewer

Javahelp is quite outdated.
Oracle help needs ADF platform & Weblogic server.

I would need to know if there are any other help template framework to create help system something like [IBM knowledge centre](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/as_ditamaps/was855_welcome_base_dist_iseries.html)

Comment: If you need a 'help template framework' then ask that, not 'how do I create a help system' - that is off-topic here. Then [edit] your question and make list of requirements. (Only) pointing to another system and saying 'like this' is not good enough here, your question should be self-contained. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.